# Having trouble understanding this example on Multidimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

For the code:

```
// Demonstrate a two-dimensional array.
class TwoDArray {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int twoD[][] = new int[4][5];
        int i, j, k = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                twoD[i][j] = k;
                k++;
            }
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + " ");
                System.out.println();
        }
    }    
}
```

The output gives me:

```
0 1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8 9

10 11 12 13 14

15 16 17 18 19
```

The question is, why isn't a new line given to every number? I mean in the for loop, if the first System.out outputted 20 times, why isn't the next `System.out.println();` outputting the same amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without braces, a `for` loop body is one statement. If we add explicit braces, then your code looks like

```
for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<5; j++) {
        System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

which is why the `println` only executes after the inner `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks so much!! :)

Answer (score 5):

If you used proper indentation, it would have been clearer :

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<5; j++)
        System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

`System.out.println();` belongs to the outer loop, so it executes once for every iteration of the outer loop, after the inner loop ends.

You can also wrap the inner loop in curly braces to make it clearer :

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<5; j++) {
        System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback! Never thought my first question would actually be answered this thoroughly and fast!